Survey and SurveyQuestion, plus Email Template, plus Flow - can it work?
We wanted to modify one of the Surveys standard Email Templates.  We modified Embed a Question.  The template looks great.  When I create a flow to use this Template, it can't function because it doesn't recognize the merge fields used by Surveys (SurveyQuestion).  Does anyone know how I can manage this? The main issue seems to be with SurveyQuestion, you can use it for merge fields, but can't identify it as an object to update or change or add a lookup or formula field.
Does anyone have any ideas to make this happen?
